# If $||B_N - B|| = 0$ as $N\to \infty$ for a bounded and invertible operator $B$, then does $||(B_N)^{-1} - B^{-1}|| = 0$ also hold as $N\to \infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, operator-theory

Suppose $B:L(X,Y)$ is a bounded and invertible operator. Suppose we have another operator $B_N$ that approximates $B$ in the sense that as $N \to \infty$ it holds that
$$
||B_N - B|| = 0.
$$
Then, does it also that hold that
$$
||(B_N)^{-1} - B^{-1}|| = 0,
$$
as $N\to \infty?$

Comment: Yes, because the invertible operators are open in $L(X,Y)$ and the inversion operation is continuous.

Comment: This is standard text book material. Many books have  a proof.

Comment: @s.harp Ok, I've tried to refresh some of this material just now as I haven't used it in a long time. I'm not sure why you say we require the the openness of the set of invertible operators in $L(X,Y)$. Can we not simply say that $$\lim_{N\to \infty}||f(B_N)-f(B)||=0$$ since $$\lim_{N\to \infty}||B_N-B||=0$$ where $f$ is the inversion operation by using the continuity of $f$?

Comment: @ManUtdBloke inversion is only well defined for invertible operators. If this set were not open you would have a sequence $B_N$ consisting of non-invertible operators with $B_N\to B$ for some invertible $B$, now the consideration $\|(B_N)^{-1}-B^{-1}\|\to0$ is meaningless, because $B_N^{-1}$ doesn't exist. Openness means that the sequence $B_N$ will, after some finite $n$, consist only of invertible operators and the consideration now makes sense.

Comment: Ok I see now, thanks for the clarification.