# Let $f(A) = A^{-1}$ for a bounded linear operator $A$. How do we prove that $f$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory

It seems I need to refresh some operator theory as its been quite a while since I need it. In another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3561990/if-b-n-b-0-as-n-to-infty-for-a-bounded-and-invertible-operator-b?noredirect=1#comment7323997_3561990) I asked, someone stated that the inversion operation in $L(X,Y)$ is continuous, where $L(X,Y)$ is the set of bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$.

So define $f$ such that $A \to f(A): = A^{-1}$ for $A$ in the set of invertible operators. How do we prove that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with operator theory, but in our calculus class we proved $f|_{GL_n(\mathbb R)}$ is continious (differentiable actually) using the observation
$$f(A)-f(B)=A^{-1}(I-AB^{-1})=A^{-1}(B-A)B^{-1}$$ Taking norms does the tick. Is that helpful?

Comment: Ah yes, that's fine thanks